# Build Optimizer of Angular will shake off HighCharts Export function

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using an company npm package which is providing a bar chart component with the right colors and an export function. When I use this bar chart in my project everything will work fine till I build the project with `buildOptimizer`
 on. Is there a way to stop the build process shaking off the export function without disabling the `buildOptimizer`? I have access to the npm package of my company too.

Bar Chart Component in NPM Package:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Directive, ViewChild, Input, AfterViewInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { IBarChartSeries } from '../../../interfaces/IChartSeries';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { HighchartsChartComponent } from 'highcharts-angular';
import ExportingModule from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'; //<--- Line 1
ExportingModule(Highcharts); //<--- Line 2

@Component({
  selector: 'basf-bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss']
})
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
...
}
```

As you can see only two lines needed for export

When I now import the npm package in my project and use the BarChartComponent, the Chart look like this:

[image: Chart]

When I build it with --prod the Export functionality is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied as it is from the documentation at [angular-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts#using-highcharts-modules). Since it explains and contains example code for importing the exporting feature .

> To use Highcharts modules you have to import them and provide them in
>   a factory **(required for aot)**.

You can find the list of available modules in the highcharts folder ls -la node_modules/highcharts/modules.

Hint: Highcharts-more is a exception, you find this module in the root folder. Don't forget to use the modules with the .src suffix, minimized highcharts modules are not importable.

Example:

```js
// app.module.ts
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import * as more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';
import * as exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES, useFactory: () => [ more, exporting ] } // add as factory to your providers
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to using `angular-highcharts`? As I used the `highcharts-angular` package so far.

Comment: Have you tried with the demo app from `highcharts-angular`. Have a look at the file at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts. It would be good to check if this project builds fine with `buildOptimizer`. Unfortunately, I haven't used `highcharts-angular` so my knowledge with it is very limited.

Comment: You are right, it helped me, thanks. But now again the Treeshaking Problem. They didn't add somthing to the app module

Comment: Thanks again for your help. With the ExportingModule I was able to make the call in the Charts ngOnInit which did the Trick.